# Set HTTP status code for redirect when returning a String in a Spring 3 controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-3

Is there a way to specify the HTTP status code when returning `"redirect:/new/url"` in Spring 3?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but looking at the source of `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView` it has `getHttp11StatusCode()` method that determines the HTTP status of response.

It seems like you can override the default response code by settings `org.springframework.web.servlet.View#RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE` property on request. Simply set:

```
httpServletRequest.setAttribute(View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, status)
```

before returning with "`redirect:`" view.

Comment: That's not working, and propably never did ;) https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12719

Answer (score 0):

As [noted by Scolytus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360531/set-http-status-code-for-redirect-when-returning-a-string-in-a-spring-3-controll#comment45426477_7360737), you must return a `RedirectView` with the `statusCode` set. Using the `"redirect:"` prefix will always result in a status of `HttpStatus.MOVED_TERMPORARILY` (302).

If you need the ability to return `String` from your controller method as well as `RedirectView`, you must change the method signature to return `Object`. Example:

```
@RequestMapping
public Object someMethod() {
    if (doRedirect) {
        RedirectView rv = new RedirectView("/new/url");
        rv.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY); // set our own status code
        return rv;
    } else {
        return "someView";
    }
}
```