# spring mvc controller mapping different ways

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

what is difference between this two types of  `@RequestMapping`? (in general, excluding the parameters passed to the page and mapping pages), 
the right way is to return the model or page ?

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categories", myService.listGroups());
        return "index";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/helloworld**"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Tutorial");
        model.addObject("message", "Welcome Page !");
        model.setViewName("helloworld");
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Besides url, the first one works for POST, PUT etc, the second one is GET only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is mainly syntactic. Note also that one usually declares `ModelAndView` as a method parameter instead of instantiating it.

`Model` as param + `String` view return value pros:

- easier to set model attributes (less Law of Demeter violations, if you care)
- easier to return the view value (simply return a string)

`ModelAndView` as the return value & param pros:

- encapsulates both of these in a single object, which may allow you to compose your methods better in some situations (probably chain handler methods?)
- allows for returning a non-String view, like the `RedirectView` (which, e.g., compared to String view, allows you to set the exact 3** HTTP response status without touching or even declaring the HTTP Servlet Response parameter: [Set HTTP status code for redirect when returning a String in a Spring 3 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360531/set-http-status-code-for-redirect-when-returning-a-string-in-a-spring-3-controll) )

See also:

- [When to use ModelAndView vs Model in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951609/when-to-use-modelandview-vs-model-in-spring)
- [Which is better, return "ModelAndView" or "String" on spring3 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175509/which-is-better-return-modelandview-or-string-on-spring3-controller)
- [What is the difference between return ModelAndView and return String in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988442/what-is-the-different-between-return-modelandview-and-return-string-in-spring-mv)